# How to hide placeholder onclick in material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using simple `form-field input` component as in below code

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field" >
     <input matInput type="search" placeholder="Search"  >
</mat-form-field>
```

On entering the input fieled by default the placeholder will go above.

[image]

How can i hide the placeholder on entering to the input field?

Comment: Since that is standard Material Design behavior - I don't think there is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try:

DEMO ----> [Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnufmy)

> You can also create Directive for same
>
> You can replace (click) ----> (focus) as you need

```html
 <mat-form-field floatLabel=never>
     <input (click)="checkPlaceHolder()" (blur)="checkPlaceHolder()" matInput placeholder=" {{myplaceHolder}} ">
 </mat-form-field>
```

In TS:

```js
myplaceHolder: string ='Enter Name'

 checkPlaceHolder() {
    if (this.myplaceHolder) {
      this.myplaceHolder = null
      return;
    } else {
      this.myplaceHolder = 'Enter Name'
      return
    }
  }
```

Comment: Its working fine only for the first time,When click for the first time placeholder will go but again if i click without refreshing the page placeholder has to display.But it's  not.

Comment: you  can replace (click) to (focus) if u want

Comment: How can i have cancel button to clear the input field?Tried with material input component but it is using ` [(ngModel)]="value` to trigger cancel action ,i am using ` [(ngModel)]`   to fetch json data is there any other way?

Comment: if you use reactive form than easily clear the field . if u want to use [(ngModel)] than set control to null

Comment: Sorry I didn't get yous answer.

Comment: if you are using reactive form than to clear: this.formGroup.controls.controlName.reset();

if you are using template driven form([(ngModel]) than :
this.controlName = null;

Answer (score 29):

I came into this question when looking for a way of hiding the placeholder when the input field is not empty, the solution I found is a modification of Krishna's, replacing the `mat-form-field` `floatLabel` argument from `always` to `never`:

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field
      [floatLabel]="'never'">
    <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder" required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer should have been the excepted answer!

Comment: It doesn't hide the placeholder - only disables the float behavior..

Comment: could be just `floatLabel="never"`

Answer (score 13):

you can try this solution.

use  `[floatLabel]="'always'"`

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmx272?file=app/form-field-label-example.html)

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field
      [floatLabel]="'always'">
    <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder" required>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: This just makes the label float always, correct?  Regardless of whether or not there is a value in the input.  OP asked to have the placeholder text be hidden.

Comment: use 'never' if you don't want floating

Answer (score 0):

This is a only-CSS solution that worked for me.

The first CSS directive is for when the input is focused.

The second is for when the input has a valid value and is not focused.

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label, input.ng-valid+span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make `appearance="outline"` for your form field and instead of adding placeholder in `<mat-label>`, you can add placeholder property in `input` which will disable floating effect on input click.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your full name">
</mat-form-field>
```

---

Then, to hide the placeholder on click:

CSS:

```
.mat-input-element:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```