# Remove text from above select material in Angular

Tags: angular

In the following [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/njbmrypmqmb) you can see the "Toppings" placeholder on it; when a user selects any items from the dropdown the "Toppings" text gets smaller and moves above the select.

Is there any way to remove the toppings text from above or display an empty string instead of it when the user selects anything?

Comment: In this example, Toppings isn't a placeholder but a label to let the user what type of information is related to the select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide placeholder onclick in material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763451/how-to-hide-placeholder-onclick-in-material)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">`

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-hide-placeholder-if-value-exists)

Comment: Why not just `floatLabel="never"`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
      <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your placeholder to empty string when you selected value, like this

```
<mat-select [placeholder]="toppings.value ? '': 'Toppings'" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
....
```

Comment: It is good practice to provide some explanation with an answer.